# Does Google Chrome stores translated content somewhere?

Tags: google-chrome, security

I just got info from our security team, that after you translate web page using Google Chrome "right mouse click -> translate to english" , Google Chrome "stores" this translation somewhere ( will ask where :) ) and it is not secure solution for translating some sensitive internal content. So maybe somebody knows more about it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data from page and page link are sent to https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/...
Look at network request in developer tools.

I assume that this data google use only for training their translating IOT.
It would unreasonable to expect that chrome is shipped and installed with whole bunch of dictionaries and translating algorithm.

To me, this fact does not stop me to use service, but if data are highly confidential, ...